# UIPanGestureRecognizer points on high resolution devices

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

In several places of our iOS apps, we use gesture recognizers to dismiss views interactively. The process is quite straightforward, we track the movement of the user's finger, and move the view with it.

On recent iOS devices, this has worked pretty well, but we're noticing with higher resolution devices like iPhone X, where the display is 3x scale, and refreshes very quickly, that the gestures are no longer as smooth as they should be.

I think this is due to the fact that the `UIGestureRecognizer` class is returning whole point values for `-locationInView:`, so when the interaction is slow, we are actually moving the view 3 pixels at a time, and this is noticeable on such a high-quality display.

I'm positive than on earlier versions of iOS, these points were sometimes reported in their accurate fractional values for precision. This doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Does anyone have any advice on how to improve this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There must be something else going on. On iPhone X running iOS 11.2.5, I'm receiving fractional coordinates (in 1/3 increments just like you'd expect) from pan gesture recognizer.

That having been said, you might consider using `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, etc., and then use [coalesced touches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uievent/1613808-coalescedtouches), which can provide touch information with even higher frequency (on my iPhone X, coalesced touches return 120 touches per second rather than 60 touches per second from pan gesture recognizer).

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else { return }

    if let coalesced = event?.coalescedTouches(for: touch), coalesced.count > 0 {
        // process all of the `coalesced` touches
    } else {
        // just process `touch`
    }
}
```

But before worrying about that, please provide a simple, stand-alone [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that manifests the problem you describe. Make sure the problem is really the gesture recognizer and not, for example, delays resulting in the complexity of what you're trying to perform upon each touch.

BTW, coalesced touches helps tackle not receiving touches frequently enough. If you have a lagginess problem, you can consider [predictive touches](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uievent/1613814-predictedtouches) which can be used to diminish this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well this was a weird one. Thanks to Rob's information and the claim that he was receiving fractional coordinates, I started digging more.

It turned out that the problem is apparent when we use a `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass (to only allow panning in one particular direction).

The coordinates received in the subclass' `-(void)touchesMoved:...` are indeed fractional. Somehow, using `-(CGPoint)locationInView:` in the recognizer's action callback only reports the whole values. I couldn't work out any way to work around this anomaly, other than storing the most recent value received in `-(void)touchesMoved...` and reading it in the action callback.

Thanks also Rob for your advice around coalesced touches, this is something I'll want to look into in the future.